Copy and Paste in QGIS for plugin
I want to create a plugin where I can choose a layer to copy and paste. For copying a layer, I will select the specific layer and choose the field and features. Then, for pasting the layer, I only need to select the layer to paste. Do the field names in the paste layer need to be the same as in the copy layer, or can they be different? I've already attempted to create the plugin, and everything works fine in terms of selecting the layer to copy, its fields, and features. However, when I click the button, it indicates that my feature is not selected.

While performing a copy-paste operation in a QGIS environment, the field names and data type must be the same between the layers. You can also perform copy-and-paste operations without using a plugin.

Alright, thank you for your answer. I already found the solution. It's just that I have an error in the code, which is why it is not working correctly.
